# ffmpeg как транслировать уже записанное видео?

Tags: ffmpeg

Подскажите как я могу транслировать уже записанное видео, как будто это прямая трансляция, хотя бы простой пример без динамического битрейта? Как составляется команда? Или ссылку на статьи?

Изменено:
Получилось конвертировать файл в hls, используя: `ffmpeg -re -i /user/myvideo.mp4 -f hls playlist.m3u8`

Как мне его теперь вывести, чтобы оно было доступно обращаясь к серверу например через `23000` порт?

Изменено:
Вывожу в mp4, юзая: `ffmpeg -i playlist.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4` файл создается, но получить доступ к нему не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь ты понимаешь что тебе нужен RTMP сервер, ffmpeg это не бродкастер, это конвертер видео/аудио. Как читать файл и простенько заливать его на бродкастер можно например вот так
`ffmpeg -re -i "/home/x/films/aqgy.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -acodec aac -ar 44100 -strict- 2 -ac 1 -f flv -s 1280x720 -q 10 rtmp://server:1935/`

Где -i это input то-есть ввод "/home/x/films/aqgy.mp4"
и "последний аргумент" это вывод

Как простенько запустить свой Streaming сервер, можно почитать на хабре https://habr.com/ru/company/vdsina/blog/536206/ или использовать например YouTub'овский.

Comment: На базе модуля ngnix_rmtp я раньше стримил мелкому мультики с компа на ТВ... Он подрос, сейчас ему уже не особо интересно... Но могу попробовать глянуть готовый проект... Но сразу говорю он под линуху.

Comment: Ок, почитаю, спасибо, сейчас я взял VDS, думал на нём развернуть этот сервер

Comment: Довольно долго эта развертывать, можно ещё раз уточнить? Я смогу делать псевдопрямую трансляцию из моего video.mp4? Потом я хочу выводить её на сайт через `<video>` (html 5), это будет возможным? Просто я уже 3 раза переустанавливаю свой сервер)

Comment: Было бы интересно глянуть готовый проект) У меня Ubuntu 18.04 могу поднять до 20.04

Comment: Переустанавливаешь сервер? Целиком? (O_o) Расскажи, в чём в целом смысл? Почему просто нельзя видео выложить в <video> ?

Comment: Заказчица просит сделать псевдопрямую трансляцию на сайт, заранее записанные видео выдавать за прямые трансляции с вебинарами

Comment: Я подумаю над твоим вопросом, завтра скорее всего адекватный ответ отпишу по поводу что и как соеденить. Сервер выделенка? VPS?

Comment: Изначально думал просто разделять видео на куски и загружать по очереди, но добиться плавного обновления на странице с html5 сложно, даже если делать видео через `<canvas>` да и вообще это костыль

Comment: Ок, спасибо, да сервер VPS на reg.ru взял

Comment: Ну как? Ещё не обдумывали?