# Аудио-стрим с youtube Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

решил написать скрипт для трансляции аудиопотока с youtube. Поискав в Интернете нашел несколько примеров, поковырял их и вот что вышло:

```
import pyglet
import youtube_dl

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aTYceNFDP4"

def download(url):
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192'
        }],
        'postprocessor_args': [
            '-ar', '16000'
        ],
        'prefer_ffmpeg': True,
        'keepvideo': True
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info_dict = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        ydl.download([url])

    return ydl.prepare_filename(info_dict)

def play_sound(name):
    song = pyglet.media.load(name)
    song.play()
    pyglet.app.run()

try:
    play_sound(download(url))
except:
    pass
```

Все работает, но не прям как надо. Он сначала скачивает аудио с видео, а потом запускает.
Подскажите, есть ли какие то методы, чтобы без скачивания воспроизводить аудио-поток?

Answer (score 0):

Зачем изобретать велосипед, если весь нужный функционал уже реализован в ffmpeg? Вот пример как стримить аудио дорожку с видео с cover image. Допили под свои нужды.

```
mkfifo $pipe
cat $pipe | ffmpeg -y
  -loop 1 -i cover.png
  -i pipe:0
  -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -minrate 6000k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 12000k -b:v 6000k
  -r 30 -g 30 -keyint_min 60 -x264opts "keyint=60:min-keyint=60:no-scenecut"
  -s 1920x1080 -tune zerolatency
  -b:a 128k -c:a aac -ar 48000
  -strict experimental
  -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/$broadcast_id
```

Comment: Подскажите, можете ли Вы ответить на этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1365202/423786 пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось намного проще:

1. Скачиваем mvp [mvp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpv-player-windows/)

2. Редактируем этот код:

   ```
   import subprocess

   url = input()
   subprocess.Popen(
       "start /b " + 
       "C:\\Users\\CGduuDE\\Desktop\\mpv\\mpv.exe " + 
       url + 
       " --no-video --loop=inf --input-ipc-server=\\\\.\\pipe\\mpv-pipe > output.txt",
       shell=True)
   ```